# BTC wallet recovery: I have a 12 word backup, what do I do?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-qt-setup

I have the 12 key seed phrase from a 10 year old Bitcoin-qt acct, but don't know what tool to use to turn it into a wallet. Obviously I am terrified to put the seed phrase into any ONLINE tool. I want to practice offline somehow to see if I even wrote it down properly. I tried looking thru the sourcecode: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin to see there is a word-list.. No joy.  One guy said Electrum, but it didn't help decipher the individual words, just kind of a 'put them all in', sink or swim endeavor....

Comment: bitcoin-qt has never supported the 12 words seed phrase, so has to be another wallet.

Comment: The most common English word-list for seed-phrases (AKA backup-phrases, recovery-phrases) is probably the [BIP39 word list](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039/english.txt) but early versions of Electrum [were different](https://electrum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/seedphrase.html)

Comment: seems also that seed can't be 10 year old, since Electrum introduced it in 2015.

Comment: here is one of my transactions on it.... https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/1HgRH4SaWtABDXsxYdmmWzpUFsPdqe852o

Comment: it was 17, not 12, so i rewote the question here.   https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/105825/btc-wallet-recovery-i-have-a-17-word-backup-what-do-i-do

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BTC wallet recovery: I have a 17 word backup, what do I do?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/105825/btc-wallet-recovery-i-have-a-17-word-backup-what-do-i-do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,
https://wallet.mycelium.com/

YOu may find more relevant information here as a second option.
https://wiki.trezor.io/Welcome

Comment: i appreciate the help, but it as 17 words so i re-asked it. (see comment above)